# Getting Pyspark error of 'split' is not in list while calling split() function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a dataframe as following

```
spark= SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
categories=spark.read.text("resources/textFile/categories")
categories.show(n=2)
+------------+
|       value|
+------------+
|1,2,Football|
|  2,2,Soccer|
+------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

Now when I convert this data frame to RDD and try to split each line of RDD on the basis of "," (comma)

```
crdd=categories.rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(',')[1])
crdd.foreach(lambda lin : print(lin))
```

While addding the element at position 1 to the crdd RDD, I get following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\bigdataSetup\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1504, in __getattr__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'split' is not in list
```

Note : Data in CSV format here is just so that it can be easily reproduced.

Comment: that means map is receiving List of the row then 
you need to do like this 
>>> categories.rdd.map(lambda x:x[0].split(",")[1]).take(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your data is in CSV format, you can use read.csv API:

```
categories=spark.read.csv("resources/textFile/categories")
```

modify your code as below:

```
crdd = categories.rdd.map(lambda line: line.value.split(',')[1])

for i in crdd.take(10): print (i)
```

Comment: I uderstand that that there is a module for CSV, and the CSV here is just so that it can be easily reproduced. What I am more interested is in solving  the issue.

Comment: see added code which solves your problem. Value is the column name of your data frame.